# Fazendo login no Laravel password sem hash

Tags: laravel, hash, password

Boas pessoal! 
Peguei um sistema bem antigo para fazer algumas "melhorias", usei Laravel para desenvolver um sistema que utiliza principalmente o banco de dados desse sistema.
O GRANDE problema é, as senhas salvas no BD são sem HASH.
Eu sei que é errado, já encrenquei com eles para mudar isso, mas não querem, por tanto fiquei sem saídas em relação a isso.

Minha dúvida é:

Há como fazer login no Laravel usando senhas sem HASH?

Ou alguém tem alguma ideia de como circular esse problema?

Grato!

Comment: não pode fazer o hash da senha para comparar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se pode utilizar assim, autenticação pela instância do usuário que você busca por `email` e depois compara a senha.

Lembrando como você mesmo relatou, a senha dessa forma é bem problemática.

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{

    $email = $request->get('email');
    $passwd = $request->get('password');

    $user = User::where('email', $email)->first();

    if ($user && $passwd === $user->passwd)
    {
        Auth::login($user); // logando
        return Redirect::intended('admin');     
    }

    return Redirect::back()->with('error_message', 'Dados Incorrectos')->withInput();
}
```

<sup>***Ref.***</sup>

- [Other Authentication Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#other-authentication-methods)
- [Authentication](https://laravel-docs-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authentication/#autenticacao-de-usuarios)
- [Docs - Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication)

Comment: Grato! Funcionou perfeito, só troquei o nome da função para **public function login() **