# Como customizar os campos de autenticação no Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

Estou tentando fazer um login customizado com Laravel 6, mas não está dando certo.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    request()->validate([
        'email' => 'required',
        'senha' => 'required',
    ]);

    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'senha'); 

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) { 
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }
    return Redirect::to("login")->withSuccess('Oppes! You have entered invalid credentials');
}
```

Sabendo que, o Laravel trabalha com suas variáveis padrões como email e password, já mudei na model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
   use Notifiable;

   protected $table = 'usuarios';
   public $timestamps = false;

   protected $fillable = ['email', 'senha', 'nivel_id', 'data_cadastro', 'status', 'assinante', 'site_id', 'tipo_conta_id'];

}
```

No BD as colunas estão com os nomes de: "email" e "senha", acredito que tenho que mudar este padrão de nome, ao invés de "password", mudar para "senha", pois quanto tento debugar `Auth::attempt($credentials)` ele sempre retorna falso.

Comment: Já tentou especificar o nome dos campos no `Auth::attempt()`? tipo `Auth::attempt(['email' => $credentials['email'], 'senha' => $credentials['senha'])`

Comment: Fiz o teste dd(Auth::attempt(['email' => $credentials['email'], 'senha' => $credentials['senha'] ])); e retorn falso ainda

Comment: uma opção é trocar seu banco para password então

Comment: o problema que o banco não é meu kkkk

Comment: para teste, eu mudei aqui no banco para password e retornou true, agora preciso saber como fazer isso no laravel

Comment: você pode criar uma nova migration para alterar esse campo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Personalizando uma model de usuarios Laravel 5.4 - Problema no login](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/187488/personalizando-uma-model-de-usuarios-laravel-5-4-problema-no-login)

Comment: relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/381991/fazendo-login-no-laravel-password-sem-hash/381997#381997

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altere seu modelo de usuário sobrescrevendo o método que retorna o nome do campo password:

```
public function getAuthPassword(){  
    return $this->senha;
}
```

No formulário mantenha o nome do input como "password".

Comment: exatamente isso, obrigado meu amigo, resolvido!